# I have django application running on apache+docker on port 8000:80,need to run another application with another port but not working

Tags: python, django, docker, apache, ubuntu

I have Django application running with apache+docker with 8000:80 port in ubuntu server. Now I have another Django application.

I want to run that application with apache+docker with different port 8006 or any other port. I think we can't bind two applications for the same port 80.Correct me if I am wrong and suggestions are most welcome.

I am able build docker container and service is up, but I'm not accessible on browser and requests. So, is there any way that I can do it and able to access in browser please suggest

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  test-app:
    image: test-app
    build:
      context: ./app/
    ports:
      - "8006:8006"
  #  networks:
  #    - GST
    container_name: test-app
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /storage/req_resp_files:/var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/req_resp_files
      - /storage/gst_logs:/var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/logs
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM httpd:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install django ptvsd
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
#ADD ./httpd-ssl.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#ADD ./server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
#ADD ./server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
#ADD ./gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
ADD ./GSTDP_Develop /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop
RUN chown -R www-data. /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop
RUN chown -R www-data. /usr/local/apache2
RUN a2enmod wsgi
#RUN a2enmod ssl
#RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN cd /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/
RUN pip install -r /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/requirements.txt
RUN python /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
#RUN cd /var/www/html/
#RUN tar -xvzf GSTDP_Develop.tar.gz
EXPOSE 8006
#EXPOSE 443
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

and **demo-site.conf** file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop

Listen 8006
<VirtualHost *:8006>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Alias /static /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/src/static
                <Directory /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

                <Directory /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/static>
                Require all granted
                </Directory>

                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/src/wsgi.py

                <Directory /var/www/html/GSTDP_Develop/src>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

                WSGIDaemonProcess GSTDP_Develop processes=2 threads=6 display-name=gst-dna

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       
</VirtualHost>
```

*EDIT 1:*

How it looks in Terminal
`407129a206fd   5ba         "apache2ctl -D FOREG…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8006->80006/tcp, :::8006->8006/tcp   sharp_keldysh`
`6ac03b56d3ab   gst-app     "apache2ctl -D FOREG…"   2 weeks ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp   gst-app`

but not able access url from browser.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, My bad Need to activate that port. corresponding port enabled and it's working. and small re-work regarding apache config. changed

```
Listen 8006
<VirtualHost *:8006>
```

to

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

As it apache http requests listen default to 80 port